# I have a issue with a for each loop within the html code

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, glitch-framework

I have an issue with a foreach loop within the html //view. I am attempting to change the colour of the icon depending on the weight entered. Now the code works perfect when i take it out of the foreach within the html but it only works for the last weight entered, and when its in the foreach loop the icon prints for each row, just will not show any colour. So would anyone know how i could accomplish this and thanks for your time.

```
    /////controller
index(request, response) {
const memberlistId = request.params.id;
const loggedInUser = accounts.getCurrentUser(request);

const viewData = {
  title: 'Memberlist',
  memberlist: memberStore.getMemberlist(loggedInUser.id),
  bmi: memberStore.getBmi(loggedInUser.id),
  weightClass: memberStore.getWeightClass(loggedInUser.id),
  idealBodyWeight: memberStore.isIdealBodyWeight(loggedInUser.id),
  getTrend: memberStore.getTrend( loggedInUser.id),
  timeStamp: memberStore.timestamp(),


};

    //////model
    getTrend(id) {
      const memberassessment = this.getMemberlist(id);
      const assess = memberassessment.assessments;

          if (assess.length > 1) {
            for (let i = 0; i < assess.length; i++) {
              if (assess[assess.length - 2].weight > assess[assess.length - 1].weight) {
                 const result = "green";
                 return result;
               } else {

                const result = "red";
                return result;
        }
    }
}
},


       //  The view where i'm having the problem getting icon to change colour

    <tbody>
      {{#each memberlist.assessments}} 
      <tr>
       <td>{{timeStamp}}</td>
       <td>{{weight}}
       </td>
       <td> {{chest}}   
       </td>
       <td> {{thigh}}
       </td>
       <td> {{upperArm}}
       </td>
       <td> {{waist}}
       </td>
       <td> {{hips}}
       </td>
       <td>     

       </td>
       <td>
        <a href="/memberlist/{{../memberlist.id}}/deleteassessment/{{id}}" class="ui tiny red button">Delete
         <i class="icon trash"></i></a>
       </td>
       <td>
        <a class="ui {{getTrend}} tag label"></a> //problem here keeps repeating and wont change colour
       </td> 
      </tr>
   {{/each}}   
 </tbody>
```

The expected result is that the icon will change colour in the foreach loop for each weight entered

Comment: Could you please show us your actual HTML view code? It's completely missing but would be necessary to understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: ok yeah i thought it was in

Comment: You don't use the `i` at all. Also to get the code to work, `i` should be declared outside/before of  `getTrend` function and be incremented by every call of the function.

Comment: could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (assess.length > 1) {`
        for (let i = 0; i < assess.length; i++) {
          if (assess[assess.length - 2].weight > assess[assess.length - 1].weight) {
             let result = "green";
             return result;
           } else {

            let result = "red";
            return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you cannot reassign the const keyword. Instead of const use let.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you try to achieve, but you asked for code, so here it is. What I did: use `i` in the condition; increment `i` every time it is called. I included the answer given by Mohit and used `let` instead of `const`.

```
//////model
var i = 1;
function getTrend(id) {
  const memberassessment = this.getMemberlist(id);
  const assess = memberassessment.assessments;

  if (i>=2 && assess.length >= i) {
        if (assess[i - 2].weight > assess[i - 1].weight) {
            let result = "green";
            return result;
        } else {
            let result = "red";
            return result;
        }
 }
 ++i;
}
```

I think you might want to check whether the assements are in ascending or descending order. For this, the code would be like this:

```
//////model
function getTrend(id) {
  const memberassessment = this.getMemberlist(id);
  const assess = memberassessment.assessments;

  for(i=2; assess.length >= i; ++i) {
        if (assess[i - 2].weight > assess[i - 1].weight) {
            //green
        } else {
            let result = "red";
            return result;
        }
  }
  let result = "green";
  return result;
}
```